# Limit leaflet cluster group expand depth

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am using cluster group. But how to limit cluster expand level. Suppose default cluster group loads with continent level then click. It expand to deeper level and when third time click on cluster group again it expand to country level. I want to fix three expand level of cluster group not below country level.

I tried freezeAtZoom() but it stops the cluster group from expand even from first level..

Comment: Please what do you mean by "limit expand level"? showing individual markers at a given zoom instead of clusters? keeping clusters as is (no more splitting)?

Comment: When cluster is getting clicked it's getting expanded to some level and it's happening recursively till bottom level. I want it to be limit till three click level. After that if cluster is still there it should not expand. I don't want to go till bottom level.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is still a little bit unclear.

Note first that when clicking on a cluster, it zooms to the extent of its child markers. This could represent a few zoom levels, depending on the actual child markers. It could even be directly the map's maximum zoom level, if all markers are really close one to each other. So there is no predefined target zoom level that the map will go to when you click, it all depends on the markers in that cluster.

Now if these markers do not change, and you can record the **exact map's zoom level** at which you want your clusters to no longer split apart on clicking, you have several ways to achieve that:

- Define the map's [`maxZoom`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-maxzoom) option to that zoom level, so that your users cannot go any deeper.
- Add a map's [`"zoomend"`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoomend) event listener, so that if user goes deeper that your known zoom level, you freeze the cluster group to that recorded zoom. Remember that [`.freezeAtZoom(frozenZoom)`](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.Freezable#api-reference) can take an argument to specify at which zoom level the clusters should be frozen at, no matter the current zoom level.
- Replace your individual markers by their equivalent cluster at your recorded zoom level ("country level"), maybe use Leaflet.markercluster [`singleMarkerMode`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#other-options) option for styling, and [`iconCreateFunction`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#customising-the-clustered-markers) option to override the counts and make them appear as if the clusters had many markers.

Comment: [maxZoom](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-maxzoom) solved the problem. But zoomlevel is fixed now so cluster is pointing to some wrong location. Not exact location. Earlier when it was expanding then was going to exact place.

Comment: If you need further help, please provide some code and ideally reproduce your issue on Plunker / JSFiddle / JSBin, etc. so that we can understand your situation better.